# Airflow tasks are scheduled but does not run

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

In recent times, we are observing significant execution time spikes for our pipelines.
Upon investigation, I found Airflow tasks remain in scheduled state for longer times. Most of the times, I see only 6-8 workers executing tasks.

**Environment:** Airflow 2.2.1 on AWS EC2(Linux)

**Aiflow.cfg:**

```
executor = LocalExecutor
parallelism = 32
max_active_tasks_per_dag = 16
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
```

[image]

[image]

**Pool Status**
[image]

**Worker status:**
[image]

**A few failed attempts:**

1. Moving some jobs to different pool
2. Restarting Airflow.

Can someone help me configuration is causing this?
How can I make sure, we are using all workers properly?

Answer (score 0):

Known issue in Airflow and fixed in later versions. Upgrading Airflow version fixed the issue.

[More details here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19622)